# CDbCriteria error in yii

Tags: yii

I want to display email inbox with read and unread status and also display them in descending order. Here is my code:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->order = 'emailid DESC';
 $model = Email::model()->findAllByAttributes( 
            array(
              'to_userid' => Yii::app()->user->id,
            ), 
            array(
              'condition' => 'email_status=2 OR email_status=1',
            ), $criteria
          );

          $this->render('inbox', array(
               'model' => $model,
          ));
```

But this is not working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think thats the right way of using `cdbcriteria`. Here, try this:

```
 $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
 $criteria->condition = 'to_userid=:userId AND (email_status=2 OR email_status=1)';
 $criteria->params = array(':userId'=>Yii::app()->user->id);
 $criteria->order = "emailid DESC";
 $model = Email::model()->findAll($criteria);

 $this->render('inbox', array(
        'model' => $model,
 ));
```

This should work. Hope that helps. :)